# Why login.jsp page is loaded into a DIV?

Tags: jquery, jsp, authentication, tabs, weblogic

Background: My Java EE project runs on Weblogic. There is a page having three tabs (using jQuery). Each tab will load a specific page/file when users click. Everything works fine so far.
    However, the Login page is loaded into current tab area when user's session is timeout. My question is how to not load the login page into tab (but just like a fresh page).
    Many thanks for your help/comments

Comment: Have the server return a different status code in the event that the user isn't logged in, such as 403. Then, the ajax request will fail and you can catch it with `ajaxError` to perform the redirect.

Comment: we'll need to see some code that demonstrates the situation, or at least the pertinent parts of the code